How to generate a custom token address?
I used the command:
solana-keygen grind to find the address containing the suffix I wanted.
However when I used the command:
spl-token create-token keypair
It gave me an error that the address was already in use, I tried many different types of keypair but still got this error.
Can anyone guide me how to create a token with a custom suffix address?

The error you are encountering as the error suggests show's that you've already initialized a new token mint with said keypair
Grind for a new token mint address and create your token.

